# Advance Command Line FTP Client?

Tags: networking, ftp

The Default Microsoft Command Line FTP Client does not support some commands like AUTH, SITE & CONNECT. Is there any other Command Line FTP Client available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coreftp.com/

has many options including command line support

psftp[1] has support for batch processing, it could be interesting too. And supports wildcards.

[1] http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter6.html

Comment: I am finding Core FTP's command line functionality severely lacking. E.g., it has no support to upload multiple files at once, apart from uploading an entire folder.